# Memory consumption of static methods

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, static, static-methods

I have lot of static functions in my web application.
I do not have any static class and static properties or variables.
All the classes are normal classes only the methods are static.

How is memory allocated to static functions if they are in a normal class?
Will this cause any memory or performance issue?

Comment: Other than the code itself being loaded into memory so it can run, the functions operate memory wise the same way instance functions would. It depends on how you are allocating and controlling the lifetime of the objects you create inside the methods, it doesn't really have anything to do with the methods being static or instance.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is allocated in the heap when you new up the objects. That does not change anything. The static class then gets it as parameters that technically are heap pointers.